# Reconnect Mac and iPhone in background mode with BLE

Tags: macos, core-bluetooth

I implement `Mac` app as central, `iPhone` app as peripheral.

Central can connect/reconnect with peripheral when `iPhone` is in FOREGROUND base on peripheral discovered by:

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

But after connecting in FOREGROUND:

- Save connected peripheral again
- Move peripheral far away central until lost connection
- Then iPhone is in BACKGROUND mode (included the UIBackgroundModes key with the bluetooth-peripheral value in your app’s Info.plist file)
- Move peripheral nearby central, after having didDiscoverPeripheral, I reconnect by do connectPeripheral with saved connectedPeripheral. But it is unstable, sometimes it works very well, sometimes it can not reconnect.

Please help me the way to reconnect in background mode between MAC and IOS.

PS: I also wonder how the knock app can do that in its introduce:

http://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/knock-strange-new-way-unlock-mac/

and

http://www.theverge.com/2013/11/5/5069614/knock-iphone-app-wirelessly-unlocks-your-mac

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you lose the connection, simply call `connect` on your saved peripheral. It will connect again as soon as possible. There is no need to continue/restart scanning, but if you do so, then use the peripheral object returned in the `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback and *not the saved one*.